# Pyomo scheduling optimization problem with non-continuous objective function

Tags: python, optimization, pyomo

I have the following optimization problem:

Assign a set of **Users** to a set of **Shifts** that minimizes labor cost. Each user has his own hourly wage but the caveat is that any hour worked above a certain *overtime threshold* needs to be counted with a wage multiplier. E.g. if the threshold if 5 hours and the shift is 8 hours then 5 hours would be paid with regular user wage and the remaining 3 with the wage multiplied by a predefined factor. And it carries over to shifts being worked later in the same date range (e.g. a week) so if a Monday shift may cause a shift on Friday to be counted for overtime.

```
Example:

threshold: 5
multiplier: 2
wage: 10,
shift duration: 8

cost = 5 * 10 + (8 - 5) * 10 * 2 = 110
```

I'm modelling my problem with pyomo library for python and I ran into an issue with

```
Evaluating Pyomo variables in a Boolean context, e.g.
```

Here is the complete example code that I'm trying to run:

```py
import numpy
from datetime import datetime
from pyomo.environ import *
from pyomo.opt import SolverFactory

users = ['U1', 'U2', 'U3']
shifts = ['S1', 'S2']  # shifts in a chronological order

user_data = {
    'U1': dict(wage=10),
    'U2': dict(wage=20),
    'U3': dict(wage=30),
}

shifts_data = {
    'S1': dict(dtstart=datetime(2020, 2, 15, 9, 0), dtend=datetime(2020, 2, 15, 18, 0)),
    'S2': dict(dtstart=datetime(2020, 2, 15, 19, 0), dtend=datetime(2020, 2, 15, 23, 0))
}

OVERTIME_THRESHOLD = 5  # hours
OVERTIME_MULTIPLIER = 2

model = ConcreteModel()

# (user, shift) binary pairs. If 1 then "user" works the given "shift"
model.assignments = Var(((user, shift) for user in users for shift in shifts), within=Binary, initialize=0)

def get_shift_hours(shift):
    return (shifts_data[shift]['dtend'] - shifts_data[shift]['dtstart']).total_seconds() / 3600

def get_shift_cost(m, shift, shift_index, user):
    shift_hours = get_shift_hours(shift)

    all_hours_including_shift = sum(get_shift_hours(s) * m.assignments[user, s] for i, s in enumerate(shifts) if i <= shift_index)

    # overtime hours are any hours above the OVERTIME_THRESHOLD threshold
    ot_hours_including_shift = max(0, all_hours_including_shift - OVERTIME_THRESHOLD)

    all_hours_excluding_shift = sum(get_shift_hours(s) * m.assignments[user, s] for i, s in enumerate(shifts) if i < shift_index)
    ot_hours_excluding_shift = max(0, all_hours_excluding_shift - OVERTIME_THRESHOLD)

    shift_ot_hours = ot_hours_including_shift - ot_hours_excluding_shift
    shift_reg_hous = shift_hours - shift_ot_hours

    return user_data[user]['wage'] * (shift_reg_hous + OVERTIME_MULTIPLIER * shift_ot_hours)


def obj_rule(m):
    s = 0

    # if a shift gets scheduled it has a negative impace on the objective function so it maximizes the number of scheduled shifts
    s = s - sum(m.assignments[user, shift] * 1000000 for user in users for shift in shifts)

    for user in users:
        for shift_index, shift in enumerate(shifts):
            # add the cost of a shift if the "user" was assigned to it (via the binary decision variable)
            s = s + m.assignments[user, shift] * get_shift_cost(m, shift, shift_index, user)

    return s

model.constraints = ConstraintList()

"""
Constraints that ensure the same user is not scheduled for overlapping shifts
"""
def shifts_overlap(shift_1, shift_2):
    s1 = shifts_data[shift_1]
    s2 = shifts_data[shift_2]

    return s2['dtstart'] < s1['dtend'] and s2['dtend'] > s1['dtstart']

for shift_1 in shifts:
    for shift_2 in shifts:
        if shift_1 == shift_2 or not shifts_overlap(shift_1, shift_2):
            continue

        for user in users:
            model.constraints.add(
                1 >= model.assignments[user, shift_1] + model.assignments[user, shift_2]
            )

"""
Constraints that a shift has only 1 assignee
"""
for shift in shifts:
    model.constraints.add(
        1 >= sum(model.assignments[user, shift] for user in users)
    )
"""
End constraints
"""

model.obj = Objective(rule=obj_rule, sense=minimize)

opt = SolverFactory('cbc')  # choose a solver
results = opt.solve(model)  # solve the model with the selected solver

model.pprint()
```

I've been reading about disjunctions and piecewise constraints but I cannot find a way to apply these concepts to my problem. Any help would be much appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This can be modeled linearly and without binary variables.

Use something like:

```
 totalHours = normalHours + overtimeHours
 normalHours <= 40
 cost = normalWage*normalHours + overtimePay*overtimeHours
```

We are lucky: overtime is more expensive so we will automatically first exhaust the normal hours.